# testing model methods with rspec and factory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have a getter/setter method in a model retrieving the last element of an array, and adding to the array (Postgresql array of strings):

```
# return the last address from the array
def current_address
  addresses && addresses.last
end

# add the current address to the array of addresses
# if the current address is not blank and is not the same as the last address
def current_address=(value)
  addresses ||= []
  if value && value != addresses.last
    addresses << value
  end
  write_attribute(:addresses, addresses)
end
```

The methods appear to be working correctly. I'm learning Rspec / Factory and trying to test this. The tests are failing and I'd be grateful for some advice on how I should do this:

```
it "adds to the list of addresses if the student's address changes" do
  student = build(:student)
  student.current_address = "first address"
  student.current_address = "second address"
  student.addresses.count.should == 2
end

Failure/Error: student.addresses.count.should == 2
     expected: 2
          got: 1 (using ==)

it "provides the student's current address" do
  student = build(:student)
  student.current_address = "first address"
  student.current_address = "second address"
  student.current_address = ""
  student.current_address.should == "second address"
end

Failure/Error: student.current_address.should == "second address"
     expected: "second address"
          got: "" (using ==)
```

Thanks in advance

UPDATE: Thank you, my amended methods which pass the test are below:

```
# return the last address from the array
def current_address
  addresses && addresses.last
end

# add the current address to the array of addresses
# if the current address is not blank and is not the same as the last address
def current_address=(value)
  list = self.addresses
  list ||= []
  if !value.empty? && value != list.last
    list << value
  end
  write_attribute(:addresses, list)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `addresses` is only in local scope, so every time you call `current_address=` it will be cleared. Try `self.addresses`.

Comment: thank you, any advice on refactoring my setter method to make it more readable? The tests passed, but after originally rewriting the method  with self.addresses throughout the tests passed but it didn't update the database when submitting the student form - is there a better way to test that the setter actually updates the database on a write (just interested, the above method is writing correctly). Thanks again

Comment: Call `reload` on the object and you'll be able to confirm if the addresses were persisted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think it's wrong.

In your test instead of adding an element to the array you are replacing it because you are assigning a new value to it.

```
student.current_address = "first address"
student.current_address = "second address"
```

What I think you should do is add a new element as you do in your code `addresses << value`

Comment: Thank you. Doing that would work, but won't test my setter method.